# Get JDBC Result set in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I get the JDBC result set using hibernate. In one case, I want to call a stored procedure, which does some calculations and selecting some of the columns from multiple tables.
So in my stored procedure I have something like

```
selct sum(c1) as TotalVal, avg(c2) as AverageVal from ....
```

So, I want to get these column values in my java code and do some more processing on that. 
However, I am not able to get the ResultSet of the procedure call in the java code.

Can anyone let me know how to do this ?

I am using Hibernate4 and so cant find `session.connection()` method. Also, I tried with `doWork()`, but how can I get the resultset from the inner class `Work`

Comment: Please post the code your using to communicate with database(call procedure).

Comment: Hibernate is a `persistence`-Framework where you can `save`. Not a "read-only-framework". You can fake it by using `views` whom are read by stateless-hibernate-sessions but hibernate will fatally crash on save to those views. I respectfully advice against this usage of hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I am using Hibernate for save purpose. But there can be exceptions for that. In one of the cases, I have to generate a report, which cannot be done with a single line query. There are temporary tables created, used views and finally aggregating the results and sending it. In this case, how do I get the resultset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Session#doReturningWork(ReturningWork)` to return your desired results from the JDBC call:

```
session.beginTransaction();
ResultObject result = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<ResultObject>() {

    @Override
    public ResultObject execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        // execute your SQL
        // create and return result object
    });
}
session.getTransaction().commit();

// work with ResultObject
```

You could return the JDBC-ResultSet directly, but I would recommend storing the values in a separate object (here: ResultObject), because the ResultSet is related to the JDBC connection which should be kept within the `execute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

doWork allows you to execute whatever you want with a Hibernate-supplied connection. So here's an example:

```
private static class MyWork implements Work {
    private List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override 
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(...)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Foo foo = new Foo(rs.getString(0, rs.getInt(1));
                result.add(foo);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Foo> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

...

MyWork work = new MyWork();
session.doWork(work);
List<Foo> foos = myWork.getResult();
```

But you should use doReturningWork(), as shown in Jack's answer.